# Estimating the Area of Antarctica Using a Scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently, I've been working on a problem in which I had to estimate the area of Antarctica with a given scale. The answer had to be given in approximate square kilometers as shown in the image. I have tried turning Antarctica into a polygon, but even then I have trouble understanding how to calculate the area. Is there any method or strategy I have to use to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: You can calculate the area using the sheolace formula, provided you know the coordinates of each vertex https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Answer (score 0):

Note that to a good degree of approximation every straight segment from the South Pole (the blue dot on your map) to the coastline is almost entirely contained into the mainland (i.e. we are approximating Antarctica with a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain)).

Now divide the $2 \pi$ angle at the South Pole in $N$ equal angles. Measure the distance "South-Pole/coastline" $d_i$ along these $N$ directions, for $i=1...N$. Now, the "true" area $A$ is approximated by the quantity $A_N$, given by

$$
A_N = \frac{\pi}{N} \sum_{i=1..N} d_i^2
$$

Increase $N$ at will to get better and better approximations.

PS: clearly the "star domain" approximation works better if you consider that the Ross and Ronne ice shelves enter into the area computation. You may also find a "better center" than the geographic South Pole, which is probably a bit on right of the South Pole (a good center for this operation is a point such that all the segments to the coastline are entirely contained into the mainland).

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly a star domain is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You don't really need to know what a star domain is from the technical point of view (at least not for this problem). A star domain is a region that has this property: there exist a point P inside the domain such that every segment from P to any other point of the domain is completely contained into the domain itself.

Comment: If you draw a star you can see that such a point P exists (and in general P is not unique).  Antarctica is almost a star domain. Egypt, France, Mongolia and many other countries are good examples of "star domains". Thailand, Japan are definitely not  star domains.

Comment: Moreover: remember that mine is not THE answer, but it is just one of the 100 funny ways of doing what you're asking for.